# Split an array into an array of lists

Tags: python, list

I have an array that has the similar to the following:

```
my_array = [['ex1' '24.59' '45.654'], ['ex2' '65.87' '64.68'], ['ex3' '654.485' '78.13']]
```

And I want to split it so I have a sort of array of lists, ideally it would print out as:

```
my_new_array = [['ex1', '24.59', '45.654'], ['ex2', '65.87', '64.68'], ['ex3', '654.485', '78.13']]
```

Comment: Am I missing something? You may have copy/pasted the same thing twice as they look identical to me.

Comment: @Chrispresso The first one is missing commas, so it is not valid Python code (unless Python 3.8+ is used, in which case `'ex1' '24.59' '45.654'` is the same as `'ex124.5945.654'`).

Comment: @kaya3 oh I definitely missed that lol. Technically it is valid Python code but it will concatenate the strings together. So you will have a list with one element in it. Each being a long string

Comment: @Chrispresso the second one has commas between each string in the array

Comment: I don't think you can split it in any reasonable way based on the string. There is no consistency between the numbers. Different number of significant figures, different number of values before and after the decimal, etc. How did the array get into that notation? You may have an easier time modifying however it got that way.

Comment: In python, this: `['ex1' '24.59' '45.654']` is technically this: `['ex124.5945.654']`. You need to write code to split the latter.

Comment: Better to just change the code declaring `my_array`, to add commas where it's created, rather than try to fix it with other code afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to flatten your container which could be a list in a list or some sort. Use the code below.

```
def container_flattener(input_list,output_list=list()):
    for item in input_list:
        if isinstance(item,list):
            container_flattener(item,output_list)
        elif isinstance(item,tuple):
            container_flattener(item,output_list)
        elif isinstance(item,set):
            container_flattener(item,output_list)
        elif isinstance(item,range):
            container_flattener(item,output_list)
        else:
            output_list.append(item)
    return output_list

l = [1, 2, [3, 4, (5, 6)], 7, 8, set([9, 10]), [11], range(12)]
print(container_flattener(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know how did you got the first array?
in this situation the python interpreter sees every element in the "array" as a string and a list in the same time and every element would look like that ex265.8764.68 for example.
i would recommend you to see why it is printed like that or if you can tell us why it would be helpful.